# Where Google Maps keep cached map files?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-file

If I type `ok maps` I cache a particular area from the Google Maps to my mobile device. Is there any folder where these files are stored? I dived into folders but found nothing that can possibly be such place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Ask app usage questions e.g. on android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no visible location where the maps are saved, on Android devices some of the pointers are saved to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/cache` but other then that it's all saved on hidden cache partition.

if you want to back up the maps folder you can use [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=38431100).

Comment: At my case backup with Titanium Backup is not a solution that I wanted but it seems that this is the best answer that I can get.